# C++/OpenCV Bicubic resize of an RGB image

Tags: c++, opencv, resize, bicubic

I want to resize an RGB image with the Bicubic interpolation. I used the following code :

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    string fileName = "myImage.jpg";

    Mat imageSrc = cv::imread(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);   // Read the file
    if (!imageSrc.data) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Loaded " << fileName << " (" << imageSrc.channels() << " channels)\n";

    imageSrc.convertTo(imageSrc, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0, 0.0);

    int SliceSizeWidth = imageSrc.cols / 2;
    int sliceShiftWidth = imageSrc.cols / 4;
    int sliceWidthNumber = (imageSrc.cols / sliceShiftWidth) - 1;

    int SliceSizeHeight = imageSrc.rows / 2;
    int sliceShiftHeight = imageSrc.rows / 4;
    int sliceHeightNumber = (imageSrc.rows / sliceShiftHeight) - 1;


    for (int sliceIndexHeight = 0; sliceIndexHeight < sliceHeightNumber; sliceIndexHeight++)
    {
        for (int sliceIndexWidth = 0; sliceIndexWidth < sliceWidthNumber; sliceIndexWidth++)
        {
            Mat patchImage = imageSrc(Rect(sliceIndexWidth*sliceShiftWidth, sliceIndexHeight*sliceShiftHeight, SliceSizeWidth, SliceSizeHeight));

            Mat patchImageCopy;
            patchImage.copyTo(patchImageCopy); // Deep copy => data are contiguous in patchImageCopy

            Mat imageBicubic;

            resize(patchImageCopy, imageBicubic, Size(2 * patchImage.cols, 2 * patchImage.rows), INTER_CUBIC);
        }
     }
     return 0; 
}
```

My problem is that even if `imageBicubic.channels()` = 3, when I want to access the second and the third channels, I can't.

I used this line : `cout << imageBicubic.at<float>(25,25,1) << endl;` in order to see if the second channel was filled, and it seems that it was not (the dims of my image are 756*1200*3). The .exe just stop working. Without the `cout`, the .exe works fine.

Do I have something to add on the `resize` fonction to get a 3D Mat at the end ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: That call to [`resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) looks flakey. You pass `INTER_CUBIC` as the 4th parameter, but if you read the signature, you'll notice that it should be the 6th one. Right now you're setting `fx` to 2, and using linear interpolation.

Comment: Also, rather than `imageBicubic.at<float>(25,25,1)`, I'd consider using `imageBicubic.at<Vec3f>(25,25)[1]`.

Comment: One more comment -- careful about the "3D Mat" thing. While it looks like it, technically it's a 2D `Mat` with 3 channels. While you can create 3 (or more) dimensional `Mat`s, you'll find that many of the image processing functions won't work with them.